# Regular expression for Arabic in python

Tags: python-2.7, arabic

I wrote this code to decode any ِsubString like that "أنا مبسوطة"
the problem is that can accept "أنا  سيشسيسشي مبسوطة  "

```
 s=ur"أنا  سيشسيسشي مبسوطة  "
        pattern=ur"أنا"+"\s"+".*"+ur"ة"
        l=re.findall(pattern,s)
        print(pattern)
        for tweet in l:
           print(tweet)
        length=l.__len__()
        if (length>0):
           print ("true",length)
        else:
           print ("false")
```

I want the output be true if input  "أنا مبسوطة" else if input "أنا  سيشسيسشي مبسوطة  "  false . I am using python 2

Comment: Is it your home work? your pattern will find both of the inputs, given any, it will give length greater than 0,

Comment: ok, I want  edit the regular to accept only "أنا مبسوطة" and the others like it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern instead:

```
pattern=ur"أنا"+"\s*"+ur"[ا-ي]*"+ur"ة"
```